# Getting the starting address of DRAM or SRAM galaxy S7

Tags: c, android-studio, linux-kernel

Im using NDK tool in android studio to program C for android devices.I want to know how i can get the starting address of SRAM or DRAM samsung galaxy S7.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're confused about the nature of the NDK. The NDK does not let you write programs which run on the "bare metal" of the Android system. As such, the "starting address" of SRAM / DRAM resources is not available (and is not meaningful) to NDK code.

NDK libraries run in an environment that is similar to Linux userspace. They run as userspace processes, and allocate memory using standard Linux APIs (like `malloc()` or `mmap()`).